# Validate field depending on its value url symfony

Tags: symfony, validation, constraints

I would like to know if you can validate a field depending on its value from a form in Symfony?
For example, I have an url and a name within a form associated to it. If the value of the name is 'instagram' let's say, I want that the url to be validated by the class Instagram Validator and so on. I wrote a switch but I get the error:

Call to a member function buildViolation() on null

What I've tried:

```
public function validateURL($url, $name)
{
    $message = '';
    switch ($name) {
        case "Instagram":
            $instagramValidator = new InstagramValidator();
            $instagramValidator->validate($url, new Url());

            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    return $message;
}
```

InstagramValidator:

```
class InstagramValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function validate($url, Constraint $constraint)
{
    if (!preg_match('/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?instagram\.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[\w\-]*\/)*([\w\-]*)/', $url)) {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $this->formatValue($url))
            ->addViolation();
    }
  }
}
```

So there is a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got this error because you didn't pass `$context` to validator's constructor.
Create your own constraint and use it via `Validation::createValidator()->validate()`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;

class Instagram extends Regex
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(['pattern' => '/your regex/']);
    }

    public function validatedBy(): string
    {
        return Regex::class . 'Validator';
    }
}
```

Now you can use it:

```
$violations = Validation::createValidator()->validate($url, new Instagram());
```

Also, you can use your own validator, you just have to set it in `validatedBy` function of your constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check that in a bit.